# Any benefit to including the "return" keyword in a pipelined function?

Tags: oracle

**Is there any benefit to including the "return" keyword?**

Several websites show examples of pipelined functions in Oracle using the "return" keyword after they have done all of the pipeline statements.

Functions not including return will work just fine, such as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION return_test
RETURN qt_01_t PIPELINED IS

BEGIN

    PIPE ROW(qt_01_row_t('pipe this'));

END;
```

VS.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION return_test
RETURN qt_01_t PIPELINED IS

BEGIN

    PIPE ROW(qt_01_row_t('pipe this'));

    RETURN;

END;
```

[Oracle documentation for pipelined functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm)

[Ask Tom question on pipelined functions](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4447489221109)

Comment: IIRC it was compulsory in 10g and optional in later versions.

Comment: Quoting from your first link: "A pipelined table function must have a RETURN statement that does not return a value. The RETURN statement transfers the control back to the consumer and ensures that the next fetch gets a NO_DATA_FOUND exception." So at least in 10g, it was mandatory (as @APC already mentioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Oracle 11g documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm) and the [Oracle 12c documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#ADDCI4699):

> A pipelined table function must have a RETURN statement that does not
>   return a value. The RETURN statement transfers the control back to the
>   consumer and ensures that the next fetch gets a NO_DATA_FOUND
>   exception.

(this section is identical to the 10g documentation your link points to)

So although the parser might accept a pipelined function without a `RETURN` statement, I guess you should always add it to be on the safe side.